# How can it be shown that for some prime p, $\mathbb{Q}$[$\sqrt{p}$, $\sqrt[3]{p}$] = $\mathbb{Q}$[$\sqrt[6]{p}$]?

Tags: field-theory

I was told to consider the degrees but I'm not sure how the degrees of the polynomial so can help me here.

Comment: Can you show one inclusion?

Comment: "Degree of a polynomial" is a tricky concept in this setting. I personally don't think it's the right way to think about this at all.

Answer (score 5):

We have

$$\sqrt p=\left(\sqrt[6]p\right)^3\;,\;\;\sqrt[3]p=\left(\sqrt[6]p\right)^2\implies \Bbb Q(\sqrt p,\,\sqrt[3]p)\subset\Bbb Q(\sqrt[6]p)$$

But on the other hand

$$\frac16=\frac12-\frac13\implies\sqrt[6]p=\frac{\sqrt[2]p}{\sqrt[3]p}\implies\Bbb Q(\sqrt p,\,\sqrt[3]p)\supset\Bbb Q(\sqrt[6]p)$$

Comment: Note that the question uses $[]$, not $()$. You're not allowed to divide by $\sqrt[3]p$.

Comment: @Arthur If $\;F\;$ is any field, then $\;F[w]=F(w)\;\iff \;w\;$  is algebraic over $\;F\;$ . These *are* fields. You can divide by whatever you want as long as it is not zero.

Answer (score 1):

With $\alpha=\sqrt p$, $\beta=\sqrt[3]p$, $\gamma =\sqrt[6]p$ we have $\alpha=\gamma^3$, $\beta=\gamma^2$ and $\gamma = \frac 1p\alpha\beta^2$.

Comment: This is polynomial rings, not field extensions, so you cannot divide by $\beta$. Say $\gamma =\alpha\beta^2/p$ instead, and you're there.

Comment: @Arthur All these are *fields* since they are extensions generated by *algebraic elements*

Comment: @Joanpemo As this problem is written, with $[]$ instead of $()$, I would avoid dividing as a matter of principle in a problem as basic as this. If you want to prove that dividing is allowed (i.e. that we're in a field), then that should be done explicitly. Not assumed implicitly.

Comment: @Arthur Thank you. You can avoid dividing if you want. The question's tagging is "field theory" and that these are fields is one of the most basic theorems that are studied here when beginning to study algebraic extensions and stuff. I don't think anything beyond what has been shown has to be proved, just as I don't think that I have to prove $\;2\cdot3=6\;$ when dealing with high school things.

Comment: @Joanpemo I didn't see the tag, and to be honest the brackets might be a typo. It was just something I noticed that I assumed was part of the problem. In other words, that the problem implicitly was "show that these two rings are equal even without assuming that they are fields". But I agree that I'm being a bit pedantic.

Comment: @Arthur Duely noted though I agree with Juanpemo that the distinction is moot for algebraic extensions

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the intend solution was this:

- Clearly $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{p},\sqrt[3]p]\subset \mathbb Q[\sqrt[6]p]$.
- One can check that $\mathbb Q[\sqrt[6]p]$ is a degree $6$ extension of $\mathbb Q$.
- By considering the subfields $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{p}]$, $\mathbb Q[\sqrt[3]{p}]$ of $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{p},\sqrt[3]p]$, the latter must have degree $\ge 6$.